# Optimization level in GCC for reducing executable size

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

I am learning optimization by gcc. From [Optimization levels](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_49.html),it is given that in level Os , gcc specifically select optimization required to reduce size of executable.
I wrote simple program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int k=7;
    printf("k = %d\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

And tested for all levels.
It gave me size as follows

```
O0 - 4883
O1 - 4883
O2 - 4867
O3 -4867
Os - 4879
```

It should give least size in level Os . But it did not do so.
Can anyone please tell me if I am wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Also beware of minimum file sizes on your current file system. Read http://timelessname.com/elfbin/ for all the madness required to shrink a program below a certain size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of the Optimization Levels as a guideline style for the compiler, they will never guarantee the smallest or fastest executable but will build the code in a way best suited the the level of optimization you are aiming for.

0s will not test all levels then pick the smallest executable, it will just build using rules that tend towards smaller executable sizes rather than faster execution for example.

Add a few loops to your program so it has more options for the compiler then you might start to see some more significant differences.  If you really want to understand the differences in Optimization Levels then start disassembling the executable and see what assembly code the compiler produced and compare the various styles.